# Notification Option in Firebase Assitance is not showing

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-assistant

The Notification Option in Firebase Assitance is not showing. I search a lot but i did not find solution. if You know please help I am beginner

[image]

[image]

Comment: Typically screen shots of code are not helpful. Please post the code and configuration you have so far as *TEXT*.

Comment: @RyanNerd The Firebase Assistant is a GUI add-on to Android Studio. In this case the screenshots seem the only way to show that OP is looking for.

Comment: @Farooq: To be able receive notifications in your app, just add the Cloud Messaging library. To do more advanced things, see the links in SHRAIYSH's answer below.

Comment: Thanks for Your Help.  But i only want to show an option of Notification in firebase assistance Like other Admob, Invites, Storage and etc.. But now I find the solution without it....Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Notifications in Firebase are handled with Firebase Cloud Messaging. Refer [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/). Also, as an example, refer this [code](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/68a320d32688aea964360f8fd3ede15c9c49dd8a/messaging)